# What am I supposed to using this toJson function for?

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I copied this code from somewhere online that said that it is good to use a `model` for your data interfacing. I've used the `fromJson` function a lot so far, but never the `toJson` function since anytime I need to write data to Firebase the built-in functions let me write in the `JSON` right then and there. When should I be using this `toJson` and how would I use it?

```
  ModelFriend.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic>? json): //Transform JSON into model
        createDate = json?['createDate'] as String,
        modifiedDate = json?['modifiedDate'] as String,
        stat = json?['stat'] as String,
        uid = json?['uid'] as String,
        username = json?['username'] as String;

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> toJson() => <dynamic, dynamic>{ //Transforms model into JSON
    'createDate': createDate,
    'modifiedDate': modifiedDate,
    'stat': stat,
    'uid': uid,
    'username': username,
  };
```

Comment: Hi, did my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we want to add documents to Cloud Firestore in Flutter, we can use the following code:

```
await firestore.doc(documentPath).set(data);
```

The type of the `data` variable is `Map<String, dynamic>`, so you need to convert the model to a map like this:

```
final Model model = Model(
  name,
  email,
);

await firestore.doc(documentPath).set(model.toJson());
```

Also, if you use the code below, you may enter the wrong field and get an error:

```
await firestore.doc(documentPath).set({
  "naem": name, // Typo, "name" becomes "naem"
  "email": email,
});
```

So, the answer is, we need `toJson` to convert the model to a map and add it to Cloud Firestore.